# How to create a namespaced model instance in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inherited-resources

I have this model:

```
class Backend::Enterprise < ::Enterprise
```

How could I call and instantiate this model in its namespace?

If I write, in `backend_enterprises_controller`:

```
@enterprise = Enterprise.find(1)
```

It calls to the model:

```
class Enterprise < ActiveRecord::Base
```

And I'd like to have separated methods in each namespace model.

Is it possible? I'm using Rails 3.2.14 and inherited_resources gem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but have you tried

```
@enterprise = Backend::Enterprise.find(1)
```

?